# Making react native TopNavigation bar absolute

Tags: react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

So what i want to achieve is a navigation bar that has a background color of blue and have a 60% opacity so that it can show the image behind it. I can only achieve this by making the header's position an absolute but it wont let me click the back button.

here is my code stacknavigator

```
const UnregisteredNavigator = () => {


return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={({ navigation,route  }) => ({
        headerStyle: {
          height: 60
        },
        header: ({}) => {
          return (
            <ThemedTopNavigation navigation={navigation} route={route} />
          );
        },
    })}
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="LandingScreen" component={LandingScreen} options={{headerShown:false}} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={SignInScreen}  />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

and here is my ThemedTopNavigation code

```
const TopNavigationBar = ({ navigation: { goBack },route,eva }) => {
  const themeContext = React.useContext(ThemeContext);
  console.log("styled", eva);

  const [menuVisible, setMenuVisible] = React.useState(false);
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);


  const onCheckedChange = (isChecked) => {
    themeContext.toggleTheme()
    setChecked(isChecked);
  };
  const backFunction = () => {
    alert("back");
    // goBack()
  };

  const renderBackAction = () => (
    <TopNavigationAction style={{backgroundColor:"red",zIndex: 1, position:'relative'}} icon={BackIcon} onPress={backFunction}/>
  );
  return (
    <Layout  style={eva.style.navLayout}>
        <TopNavigation
                style={[eva.style.navContainer, styles]}
                alignment='center'
                title={()=>(<Button>CLICK</Button>)}
                accessoryLeft={renderBackAction}
              />
      </Layout>
  );
};
```

I am using UI kitten. anyone can help me?

Comment: You should not be using position absolute you need to have container whose position is relative, then you need to have child in it and that child you need to use position absolute and from all sides it should be zero so that it always follows the parent element height width.
Now you need to have a background Image, very easy just use Image and make it follow the height width of parent element.
Note: You need to manage layers here, as your first child is absolute to the parent view you can now use text and back arrow in that child view.

Comment: @AliHussnain this is my app.js code `<SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
        <IconRegistry icons={EvaIconsPack} />
          <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, toggleTheme }}>
            <ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={{ ...eva[theme], ...dawataTheme }}>

              <NavigationContainer >
              { isLoggedIn ? <MainTabNavigator /> : <UnregisteredNavitator /> }
              </NavigationContainer>

            </ApplicationProvider>
          </ThemeContext.Provider>
        </SafeAreaView>`

can the navigationContainer be the parent that has relative position?

Comment: Nope you should focus on this `header: ({}) => {
          return (
            <ThemedTopNavigation navigation={navigation} route={route} />
          );
        },` you need to consider `ThemedTopNavigation`  as your parent container and then you need two child elements in this component render one for content which you can name as layer1 and second one for image you can name it as layer2.
We need layer1 to be on top of layer2 for that purpose we need to use position absolute on the layer1 and remember we need to have position relative on container element which is `ThemedTopNavigation`

Comment: @AliHussnain but can the screens render inside the my ThemedTopNavigation?

Comment: I think you are combing two things screens and TopNavigationBar they are separate entities and if you will try to combine them for sure you will end up many other things in future.

Comment: If you want to have a Layout you should create HOC component and in this component you do common things which are part of layout and then you decide where to render the child elements using `props.children`.

Comment: I would recommend never make TopNavigationBar part of a screen.